# Why can't I write in my file using a FileWriter on my local host but it works on a other machine?

Tags: java, file, filewriter

I want to write lines in a file, on my local machine the file are under `/home/localuser/Desktop/myProgram/files` and when I put them on the server machine they are under `/userhome/my_name`.

When I run the program on my local machine, it creates the output file under `/home/localuser/Desktop/myProgram/files/output.txt` and it detects if this file already exists but it doesn't write in it, neither throws any excpetions. On the server it creates and detects the file under `/userhome/my_name/output.txt` and it WRITES in it.

The code is the following one to create and make the file empty if it already exists:

```java
    private static void createFile(String fileName){
        try{
            File printerFile = new File(fileName);
            if(printerFile.createNewFile()){
                System.out.println("File created: " + printerFile.getName());
            }else{
                System.out.println("File already exists. Emptying " + fileName);
                emptyFile(fileName);
            }
        } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Problem while creating new file");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

private static void emptyFile(String filename){
        try{
            new PrintWriter(filename).close(); // make the file empty
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Problem while emptying the file");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and then to write the content :

```java
    process Printer_P{
        String messageToPrint; // used to store the message that the printer get from the client
        PrinterCommand command; // used to store the action that the client asked for

        try{ // try and catch the openning of a file writer
            out = new FileWriter(filename,true);
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Problem while openning a new FileWriter in Printer.jr");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(printerName +" " + "POWER ON");

        while(true){
            receive action(command, messageToPrint); // wait until it receive an action
            if(command == PrinterCommand.PRINT){
                System.out.println(printerName + " " + messageToPrint);
                try{ // try and catch the writting action
                    out.write(messageToPrint+"\n");
                }catch(IOException e){
                    System.out.println("Problem while writting in the output file in Printer.jr");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else if (command == PrinterCommand.CLOSE){
                try{
                    out.close();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Problem while close the filewriter in Printer.jr");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(printerName +" " + "SHUTDOWN");
    }
}
```

Why doesn't it write in the file when I'm using it on local machine but it do when it's on the server machine ?

Comment: I don't understand this: `process Printer_P{` is that java? Also, where is your main method? You don't show any of the filenames, how you're using them or entering. Maybe you should reduce this down to a very simple example using the main method and the write method you're checking.

Comment: it's JR programming it's very similar to Java and the file name I just give "output.txt" I think the problem is focused on the filewriter instead of main or anything else

Comment: We need the missing bits to help you solve the problem though. If you can reduce it down to a simple reproducible example, somebody might be able to help you.